# Issue in connecting Java thin driver in oracle 11G r2

Tags: java, oracle11g, thin, sqlexception

```
public static  Connection getConnection()throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
       { String username="scott";
            String password="tiger";

            String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521";
        Connection connection = null;
        System.out.println("before class");
                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                   System.out.println("Before connection");
                connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
           System.out.println("CONNECTED");
        return connection;
       }
```

Connection Name: orcl
UserName:scott
Password:tiger
connection details:scott@

I am using Oracle g11 Release 2 and I already included the ojdbc.jar in my build path. When trying to establish the connection, I get the following stack trace error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid connection string format,
>   a valid format is: "host:port:sid"    at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)  at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)  at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.(OracleConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.adobe.util.DBConnection$DBUtil.getConnection(DBConnection.java:23)
>     at
>   com.adobe.daoimpl.DBimplementation.registration(DBimplementation.java:21)
>     at com.adobe.service.AdobeService.registration(AdobeService.java:13)
>     at webservice.Web.service(Web.java:16)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Just solved this issue by using: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ipadress:portnumber/service_name`

Comment: It solved to me... specifically the "//" after "@"

Answer (score 4):

You are missing SID (or service name) on the end of connection string.

It has to be "host:port:sid"

Comment: Added sid and then it was showing the below error
This is what i gave.orcl is my connection name please correct if I am doing wrong 
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
It was showing me the below error after adding SID as orcl
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28000: the account is locked
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.receive2nd(O3log.java:496)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:278)

could you please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

it should be

String url=" jdbc:oracle:thin:@Localhost:1521:XE";

Answer (score 1):

Add the database `SID` in your connection string.

```
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID_GOES_HERE";
```

Comment: It was showing me the below error after adding SID as orcl
This is what i gave.orcl is my connection name please correct if I am doing wrong 
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28000: the account is locked
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.receive2nd(O3log.java:496)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:278)

could you please help me in this

Comment: ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK, Also make sure that your user has been granted the correct permissions.

Comment: No luck I doesnt know about oracle connections and all.Could please help me in this.I am creating local connection in sql developer and in the connection I am changing to Local/Bequeath and creating a database and in this I am creating tables.Is there anything that has to be done rather than this

Comment: Connect as the sys user in sql developer.  You will see "Other Users" expand this.  Right click the schema and view properties.  Within this dialog should be an option to unlock the user and grant privileges.  I do not have sql developer handy so these instructions are not exact.

Comment: I am able to connect but it says table/view is not there but I created a table with name adobetrail and checkd in sqlplus
SQL> select * from tab;
TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
ADOBETRAIL                     TABLE

Below was my console message
CONNECTED
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

 at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
 at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)

Answer (score 1):

And your SID probably is XE, so it should be jdbc:oracle:thin:Localhost:1521:XE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

I resolved it by updating my JDBC driver. In my particular case, from ojdbc7.jar to to ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar