# Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid", using TNS_Names

Tags: flyway

While making a DB connection using TNS names in the connection URL.

Getting this error

> Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"

I am Using: ojbc 6 12.1.01., JDK8, flyway version 5.2.4, maven 3.0.0.M1

Not able to connect, tried using -Doracle.net.tns_admin with maven migrate command.

Comment: can you provide your code? also this might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667815/issue-in-connecting-java-thin-driver-in-oracle-11g-r2

Comment: Hi Dina,  The Problem is not with the connection URL with host:port and SID, it works fine. Problem comes when I use tnsnmaes.ora to read the host:port and SID. I am using <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
     <locations>
      <location>classpath:db/migration</location>
     </locations>
     <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
     <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain.${Env}(TNS Alias)</url>
 I think flyway is not able to read the tnsnames.ora.